# GIT: Get commits for specific path in mono repo

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a monorepo with many projects and I want to get all the commits for a specific project.

For example: I have github.com/owner/repo and under this I have directories, web, mobile and server.
I want to fetch from Github API all the commits for one project.
I didn't find a way to do that unfortunately...

Comment: Does this need to be with the github api? If you clone the repo and use `git log --follow mobile` you should have all the commits of the mobile directory

Comment: Yes, it must be in Github API. I'm doing a compare between to two tags and I want only the relevant commits

Answer (score 4):

I too don't know if this is possible with GitHub API, but if you clone that repo locally and use Git CLI then everything is easy:

```
git clone https://github.com/example/example
cd example
git log --follow --pretty=%H -- <folder>
```

This will list all commit SHAs where any of the files in `<folder>` is changed.